# Translating the alert messages by using i18 translation library

Tags: javascript, jquery, internationalization, i18next

I wrote a code that will translate text from `en-US` to `id-ID` (Indonesian). Here button has got a text which reads as `Click me if you are serious`. After applying translation, it is getting translated as `Klik saya jika anda serius` successfully. If I click on that button, an alert message will be displayed like this: `You have been alerted, code it down`. I want that alert message to be translated to `id-ID`. Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Translation</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>
    <button onclick="alertbox();" id="btn" >Click me if you are serious</button>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="i18next-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    function alertbox () {
      alert("You have been alerted, code it down");
    }
    $.i18n.init({
        lng: 'id-ID',
        ns: {
            namespaces: ['ns.common', 'ns.special'],
            defaultNs: 'ns.special'
        },
        useLocalStorage: false,
        debug: true
    }, function(t) {
        $('#btn').text($.t('app.btn', {
            btn: ''
        }))
    });


    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

`id-ID (ns.special.json)`

```
{
    "app": {
        "btn": "Klik saya jika anda serius"
    }
}
```

`en-US (ns.special.json)`

```
{
    "app": {
        "btn": "Click me if you are serious"
    }
}
```

How can I translate alert message into `id-ID`?

Comment: Ummm.... anybody here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Translation</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css">
</head>

<body>
    <button id="btn">Click me if you are serious</button>
    <div id="qwe"></div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="i18next-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    /*$("#btn").click(function() {
        alert("You have been alerted, code it down!!!");
    });*/
    $.i18n.init({
        lng: 'en-US',
        ns: {
            namespaces: ['ns.common', 'ns.special'],
            defaultNs: 'ns.special'
        },
        useLocalStorage: false,
        debug: true
    }, function(t) {
        var key = $('#qwe').text();
        $('#btn').text($.t('app.btn', {
            btn: ''
        }))
        $('#qwe').text($.t('app.alert', {
          alert: ''
        }))
    });
    $("#btn").click(function() {
        alert($('#qwe').text());
    });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    display: none;
}
```

ns.special.json (en-US):

```
{
    "app": {
        "btn": "Click me if you are serious",
        "alert": "You have been alerted, code it down!!!"
    }
}
```

ns.special.json (id-ID):

```
{
    "app": {
        "btn": "Klik saya jika anda serius",
        "alert": "Anda telah diperingatkan, kode itu turun!!!"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Where is your problem? You dont even try :) There is everything documented:
http://i18next.com/pages/doc_jquery.html
And you can find many examples with jquery. You can find even live examples on jsfiddle, like that:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
i18n.init({
    "lng": 'en',
    "resStore": resources,
    "fallbackLng" : 'en'
}, function (t) {
    $(document).i18n();
});

$('.lang').click(function () {
    var lang = $(this).attr('data-lang');
    i18n.init({
        lng: lang
    }, function (t) {
        $(document).i18n();
    });
});
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SalvadorDali/dLc7x/

Finish your code and edit your question, so we can help you. First declare i18n variables, then use $.t

Comment: I was trying... I managed to translate button text to another language, but not alert message

Comment: But its simple as that: alert($.t("key")); so try and tell us if its works. Remember to define your plugin, and keys before your script!

Comment: It looks like you haven't understood my code. My code is complete. I'll my working code as an answer